# Giving a unique index ID for image in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with indexing process on the table. I have a multiple tables with columns as

`ID`, `camera_id`, `carpark_name`,plate, `datetime`,  `milliseconds`, `image_name`, `image`, `checked`.
`111`, `238`, `HillsZone1IN`,`MB03KTT`,`2014-08-17 16:40:30`,`680`,'MB03KTT-GBR_HillsZone1IN_2014-08-17_10-46-35-570_APPROACH.jpg`,'null',`1`

The `ID` record for the record is the location for the image in the filesystem, if the record is moved due to swap lane then the index is lost because the index is given a new id when moved to another table. This makes 90% of images on cameras where images are set to automatically confirm approach or goaway status.

IS there any way that I can revise the indexing process so that the `ID` is independent of the camera name and the record `ID`,  I was thinking like giving all images an independent index which can be moved to any table  and still point to correct location .

I have provided a simple record which has ID and  camera name .
there will be few cameras on location which has IN/OUT cameras  where images can be captured. sometimes the vehicles may use entry/exit(approach/go away) the same cameras at this time the cameras    automatically move  images to exit camera(swap lane) .
When the images move  to  new tables like if there is swap lane because the vehicles using entry/exit in the same camera. the ID on the  different table (i.e IN cam id - 111 , out camid will be having new id - '321' )  where the images fails to fetch the image.

Any suggestions would be really helpful...

Comment: Why not just save the (relative) path to your file in the table?

Comment: Apart from not including a single line of code and leaving us to guess what this mystic ID is, moving data between tables = bad idea. Sounds like more than just 1 problem, and it probably stems from completely bad data model. Include **code** while asking for help.